# Convert ESXi 5.0 & 5.5 VM's to Xenserver 6.5

Tags: vmware-esxi, xenserver, convert, ovf, vmdk

I'm looking to convert about 50 **esxi vm's to xenserver 6.5**. I am running the free version of xenserver 6.5. I've seen posts for the citrix **xen converter** tool and I've tried out the **VMware OVF Conversion Tool** with some vmdk/vmx files but did not have any luck. I also know that you can **export** VM's from vsphere as **OVF file formats** and then import into xencenter but it takes a very long time.

Has anybody done this before and had any luck with specific tools/applications?

Comment: What type of virtual machines are you looking to convert?   Windows, Linux, *BSD, Solaris, etc?  If all or some are Linux do you plan to use them in HVM or PV or PVHVM?  http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Virtualization_Spectrum

Comment: We've got a blend of Windows Server 2003, 2008, 2008R2, 2012, 2012R2, Oracle Linux and CentOS 5.10 and 6.6 VM's in our environment. I had not yet considered HVM, PV, or PVHVM. Is one option better than the other for Linux machines?